# Can bad stuff happen when calling a class from an Activity?

Tags: android

I am calling a class from my Activity.  The class I am calling doesn't extend a Service or a Activity.  It is just a worker class that I am using to process a BufferedReader object.  I am concerned that if the app loses focus during the processing of the BufferedReader I could be left with messy data.  So what happens when my Activity calls a class to perform database entries and the Activity loses focus.  I am thinking of making my worker class a Service so that I will have access to the OnPause and OnResume methods.  Not sure what I should be doing.   Does anyone else have any clues about this.

Comment: You cannot call a class. You can call **method** of **instance** of **class**.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski pedantic much

Comment: Actually, it does seem like an important distinction - the question, at least as written, doesn't display a great awareness of the fact that execution flows according to threads, regardless of what method of what class the code belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to leverage the [Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private MyWorkerClass myWorkerClass;

    void onCreate() {
      myWorkerClass = new MyWorkerClass();
      myWorkerClass.startLoading();
    }

    void onPause() {
      // You know the activity is going into the background
      // so act appropriately in your worker class
      myWorkerClass.stopLoading();
    }
}
```

The issues you describe above are very generic, so explaining any specific implementation wouldn't help.

If you wanted your worker class to complete the work even if your Activity goes into onPause then yes you would want to do the work in another Thread and possibly in a Service. You can still have your worker class though for nice OO & adhering to the SRP.

Comment: Thank you for understanding.  So basically I have two choices.  In the code you displayed I can begin my processing using a method in the processing class.  Then if the App loses focus I could handle it how ever I chose inside a different method in the processing class.  Or I can create a Service which would function independently of the initiating Activity and I wouldn't have to worry as much about using the onPause in the Activity.

Comment: exactly, there are more choices than just a Service though, ASyncTask, Loaders, Singletons etc

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `IntentService` if its a simple one-time task, or extend `Service` class if this is a continuous task. Also, have a look at `AsyncTaskLoader`.

If app process is being terminated, you need to make sure you don't leave the IO medium in a inconsistent state, or with corrupt data. So, use transactions in case of databases, write to a temporary file and replace at end in case of file IO, use confirmation requests in case of remote IO.